# How to Update XML Data into table Based on Primary Key Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have XML string like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfSpokenLanuageInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <SpokenLanuageInfo> 
       <UserID>18</UserID>
       <LanguageId>8</LanguageId>
       <Language>Basque</Language>
   </SpokenLanuageInfo> 
   <SpokenLanuageInfo>
       <UserID>45</UserID>
       <LanguageId>21</LanguageId>
       <Language>Corsican</Language>
   </SpokenLanuageInfo>
   <SpokenLanuageInfo>
       <LanguageId>27</LanguageId>
       <Language>Esperanto</Language>
   </SpokenLanuageInfo>
</ArrayOfSpokenLanuageInfo>
```

Table

```
LanguageId int 
Language Varchar(50)
UserID INT
```

Comment: OK, so **what is** the primary key in your table? How do you get this XML - as a SQL variable? What do you want to do with it exactly? You're not being very clear what your task is.....

Comment: **Typo** all throughout your XML: it's a **language** - not a "lanuage" ....

Comment: i need to update my table based on User ID

Comment: What about those entries that don't have a `UserID`??

Comment: UserId not there means skip those items

Comment: Sql Error :\The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml.

Comment: what are you trying to invoke the XML function on, then??

Comment: see already HOSPITAL_SPOKEN_LANGUAGE LanguageId 8,13 is there ok .if next time insert LanguageId 89,5,13 is there my XML so 2nd time LanguageId 89,5 only insert into HOSPITAL_SPOKEN_LANGUAGE .13 update into HOSPITAL_SPOKEN_LANGUAGE –

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming** you have this XML in a SQL variable called `@input` (and assuming you've fixed the "lanuage" to the correct spelling of "language" all over your XML) then you can use something like this to extract the info:

```
;WITH XmlData AS
(
    SELECT
        UserId = XC.value('(UserID)[1]', 'int'),
        LanguageId = XC.value('(LanguageId)[1]', 'int'),
        [Language] = XC.value('(Language)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
    FROM
        @input.nodes('/ArrayOfSpokenLanguageInfo/SpokenLanguageInfo') AS XT(XC)
)
SELECT *
FROM XmlData
```

This gives you an output something like this:

[image]

**Update:** if you want to insert only the new items and only those that do have an `UserId`, you can use something like this:

```
;WITH XmlData AS
(
    SELECT
        UserId = XC.value('(UserID)[1]', 'int'),
        LanguageId = XC.value('(LanguageId)[1]', 'int'),
        [Language] = XC.value('(Language)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
    FROM
        @input.nodes('/ArrayOfSpokenLanguageInfo/SpokenLanguageInfo') AS XT(XC)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(UserId, LanguageId, [Language])
   SELECT    
      x.UserId, x.LanguageId, x.[Language]
   FROM 
      XmlData x
   WHERE
      x.UserId IS NOT NULL
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.YourTable tbl
                      WHERE tbl.UserId = x.UserId)
```

Comment: how to Update xml data in sql server 2008 using stored procedure

Comment: @MuthuSamy: you just put this code I provided into a stored procedure ..... shouldn't be *that hard* .....

Comment: ok but i want new items insert into table existing items  update the rows how to do that

Comment: @MuthuSamy: please **tell us** what you really need and want - don't keep coming up with additional items and steps.... what do you ***really*** want? Then maybe someone can actually help you ....

Comment: i want  insert new items into table from XML ,existing items update table From XML .how to do ??

Comment: SQL-2012 Server  Error : The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml.